# How does this module in maven multi module project interact with a module that it doesn't have a dependency on?

Tags: java, maven, oop, inheritance, dependencies

To get a better understanding of real world use of inheritence/interfaces/abstraction/oop etc. I am sort of trying reverse engineer what is exactly happening in a project found on github.

The github project is an multi module maven project for algothmic trading.

After i very long time i still just dont understand how the author is able to get data from the trader-binance module and pull it into the trader-core module.

- Links to external resources (be them Git repositories or anything else) are only OK if they are supplemental to your question
  In this context i believe it should be ok to drop the link to the github project: https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-trader

Parent module : trader

child module 1 : trader-binance    -- for fetching data etc from the broker

child module 2 : trader-core    -- everything related to processing the received data

---

The trader-core module has an interface called Echange.
With in it all methods that are needed to implement an exchange (ofcourse) so you can place orders and pull data etc.

For this example ive slimmed it down to the interface below)

```
public interface Exchange<T, C extends AccountConfiguration<C>> {

    /**
     * Starts a thread that periodically sends a keep-alive message to the underlying connection.
     */
    default void startKeepAlive() { }

    /**
     * Connects to the live exchange stream to receive real time signals which will be delegated to a given {@link TickConsumer}.
     *
     * On top of the live stream, the {@link LiveTrader} will continuously check for updates on the signals of the symbols subscribed to with this method.
     * If the {@link LiveTrader} does not receive price updates within the given {@code tickInterval}, symbol prices will be polled using
     * {@link #getLatestTick(String, TimeInterval)}.
     *
     * @param symbols      a comma separated list of symbols to subscribe to.
     * @param tickInterval the frequency of the signals to be received such as every 1 minute, 1 hour, 5 seconds, etc (whichever is supported by the exchange)
     * @param consumer     a consumer of {@code Exchange}-specific candle/tick details whose data need to be converted into a {@link Candle} and then submitted
     *                     for further processing (i.e. {@link Strategy} analysis, {@link Signal} generation and potential trading by {@link Client})
     */
    void openLiveStream(String symbols, TimeInterval tickInterval, TickConsumer<T> consumer);

    /**
     * Disconnects from the live exchange stream opened with {@link #openLiveStream(String, TimeInterval, TickConsumer)}
     *
     * @throws Exception in case any error occurs closing the stream.
     */
    void closeLiveStream() throws Exception;
    }
```

The trader-binance module has a Class called BinanceExchange which implements this interface.
(Again i slimmed down the class to fit this example)

```
class BinanceExchange implements Exchange<Candlestick, Account> {

@Override
    public void startKeepAlive(){
        new KeepAliveUserDataStream(restClient()).start();
    }
    @Override
    public void openLiveStream(String symbols, TimeInterval tickInterval, TickConsumer<Candlestick> consumer) {
        CandlestickInterval interval = CandlestickInterval.fromTimeInterval(tickInterval);
        log.info("Opening Binance {} live stream for: {}", tickInterval, symbols);
        socketClientCloseable = socketClient().onCandlestickEvent(symbols, interval, new BinanceApiCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(CandlestickEvent response) {
                try {
                    priceReceived(response.getSymbol(), Double.parseDouble(response.getClose()));
                } catch (Exception e){
                    log.warn("Error updating latest price of " + response.getSymbol(), e);
                }

                consumer.tickReceived(response.getSymbol(), response);
            }

            public void onFailure(Throwable cause) {
                consumer.streamError(cause);
            }

            public void onClose() {
                consumer.streamClosed();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void closeLiveStream() {
        if (socketClientCloseable != null) {
            socketClientCloseable.sendCloseFrame();
            socketClientCloseable = null;
        }
    }
}

public interface TickConsumer<T> {
    void tickReceived(String symbol, T tick);

    void streamError(Throwable cause);

    void streamClosed();
}
```

Now my question, how does this exactly allow data being pulled from the trader-binance module into the trader core module?
as the trader-core has no dependency on the trader-binance module? What exactly is happening here/what am i missing.

I know this is a bit of an abstract question, **i would really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.**

Answer (score 0):

- Maven its a building tool. It has facility to organize projects in
  multiple sub-modules that can be build, rebuild, configured
  separately if needed. Also it helps organizing big projects in
  smaller modules with defined functionality.
- When a maven project is build it compiles java classes into class
  files, organizes in jar files that are just archives, like zip.
  Classes visibility are dictated by package names and access
  modifiers: protected, private, default and public. So when a class is
  run, it is accessed by JVM class loader using standard loading
  strategies.
- Maven is no longer relevant at JVM level, it can only    make some
  configuration of JVM used, class path parameters and    arguments
  during build time.